# Java Elasticsearch :Find Field value containing smilies :)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to retrieve all those documents from `elasticsearch` through `java api` which consist of smiles.
For example
1) this line contains smiley `:)`
2) this line doesn't contain smiley
3) this line `:)` contains smiley
I want the  `elasticsearch` to return line 1 and 3 because it contains `:)`
I tried this

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
            .setTypes(type)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery(fieldName, ".\*:).\*"))
            .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

the field mapping is field("index", "analyzed"). i tried this but get no results.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Pls post your results/try/code to get better help from the SO-Community

Comment: Thanx for reply.i have posted the tried code

Comment: ok now it needs to be formated like code and it will be better readable. You do that by using the `{} Button` and insert the code in `enter your code here`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the ) from smiley using \) ?. Usually, these systems are very vulnerable to special characters.

Comment: yes i have tried to escape like \:\\) ,  \\:\\\) but no luck

Comment: If you put a regular word like "contains", the system will return any results? In example 1 and 3

Comment: My approach will be to detect the reason for not matching. Could you replace ) with another character?  And after that : ?

Comment: yes i think the problem is in ) it  matches ":" when i remove ")" and it throws exception   when i only use ")"

Comment: Can you post the exception in a comment?

Comment: It throws the following exception"
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[ALwy2sMnTESFrG_HpV_egg][tweeter][2]: SearchParseException[[tweeter][2]: from[0],size[100]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":100,"query":{"regexp":{"tweet_text":{"value":".*:).*"}}},"explain":true}]]];"

Comment: According to this document http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html you can try two ideas. Surround :) with \" \" or replace) with \*).

Comment: I tried to surround it  with/"  /" and also replaced  ) with *) but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me.

```
    client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("index_name")
        .setSettings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().loadFromSource(jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
                .startObject("analysis")
                    .startObject("filter")
                        .startObject("tweet_filter")
                            .field("type", "word_delimiter")

                            .field("type_table", new String[]{"( => ALPHANUM", ") => ALPHANUM","? => ALPHANUM",": => ALPHANUM"})
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .startObject("analyzer")
                        .startObject("tweet_analyzer")
                            .field("type", "custom")
                            .field("tokenizer", "whitespace")
                            .field("filter", new String[]{"lowercase", "tweet_filter"})
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                .endObject()
            .endObject().string()))
        .execute().actionGet();

XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .startObject("index_type")
                    .startObject("properties")
                    .startObject("text")
                    .field("type", "string")
                    .field("index", "analyzed")
                    .field("index_analyzer" ,  "standard")
                    .field("search_analyzer" ,  "standard")
                    .field("analyzer" , "tweet_analyzer")
                    .endObject()
                    // moremapping
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject();
            client.admin().indices().preparePutMapping("index_name")
                    .setType("index_type").setSource(builder).execute().actionGet();
```

And we can search these smiles like this.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName)
        .setTypes(type)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("text", ".*\\:\\(.*"))
        .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

And its complete description   is given in following link.
[link](http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/03/04/preserving_specific_characters_during_tokenizing_in_elasticsearch.html)